# Creating a multi-page app in iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

What would be an effective way to create an app with multiple pages, almost like a book? I want to create a small, but hopefully concise guide to keeping birds as pets. Nothing groundbreaking.

I imagine there would be a contents page and then perhaps 20-30 inidividual pages that deal with individual topics such as what you need, types of food, diseases etc

I have a little experience with dev, but in my journey so far I can only imagine creating a new class (.h/.m/.xib) for each page, building the content in IB and then linking them, thereby giving about 30 classes!

I am aware it's possible to incorporate PDF's, but is this an effective route? I'd like to build a little interactivity within the content, for example a searcvh bar and hopefully a 'symptoms' search that narrows down potential diseases.

I just need a little push in the right direction and I'll learn from there. I just thought I'd ask for a little guidance beforehand.

Many thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For contents and topics take a look at [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). if you don't know it already.

Don't create 30 individual classes. The OO way could be to create a Page class and reuse that. Say someone tabs on 'dog' on your UITableViewController, you would then probably give a reference to the 'dog' content to your Page class in some way and push it onto the stack. Doing something like that you actually won't be needing IB at all.

If you go for pdf, take a look at [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), however, if you want the content to be interactive it's probably not what you are looking for. I'd say that this part completely depends on how you want to represent your content.

I hope this gives you some kind of 'push' :)

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd build an (or find an existing) app framework for displaying HTML-based content.  HTML would give you the interactivity you want, and the ability to reformat the display for different screen sizes/orientations.

Alternatively you could publish your work as an iBook.  The format for that is ePub and is rooted in HTML also.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at something like phoneGap and use it with the sencha touch framework. You'll have a native app and you have the ease of HTML markup for the individual pages.